# QueryDSL - hierarchical entities

Tags: spring, jpa, querydsl

Is there a way to force initialization of the following structure?

```java
class Dataset {
    private Dataset parent;
    private String name;
}


QDataset.datasetEntity.parent.name.isNotNull(); // parent == null, NullPointerException
```

I assume complete initialization is not possible as mindlessly initializing parent of a parent of a parent etc will eventually cause `StackOverflowException`. But is there a way or trick to make it working? In fact I only need the parent to be initialized properly so only 1 level up the hierarchy.

---

As pointed out in the comments this is possible using `@QueryInit`. In my case something like below helped.

```java
class Dataset {
    @QueryInit({"parent.name"})
    private Dataset parent;
    private String name;
}
```

Comment: Yes, this can be achieved through @QueryInits

Comment: Thanks, I git it working.